# Making footer height less?

Tags: html, css

I want to make black footer height very less almost equals to yellow sticky footer beneath it. I have tried text int the footer to `display:none` but no use.This footer picture whose height i want less is 
[image]

Website [demo](http://www.uaepap.org/arabic/HomePage.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting:

```
overflow-y:hidden;
height:1em;
```

Comment: Do that to both the Footer and Holder classes.

Comment: thanks it changes the height but i want that yellow footer beneath that black footer it makes yellow footer above black

Comment: You can adjust the `z-index` property of the black/yellow footers. For example, setting `z-index:-1` on the black one puts it beneath the yellow one (if the z-index of the yellow one is greater than the black).